# Python 3 porting workflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, porting

I have a small project I want to try porting to Python 3 - how do I go about this?

I have made made the code run without warnings using `python2.6 -3` (mostly removing `.has_key()` calls), but I am not sure of the best way to use the 2to3 tool.

> Use the 2to3 tool to convert this source code to 3.0 syntax. Do not manually edit the output!

Running `2to3 something.py` outputs a diff, which isn't useful on it's own. Using the `--write` flag overwrites something.py and creates a backup.. It seems like I have to do..

```
2to3 something.py
python3.0 something.py
mv something.py.bak something.py
vim something.py
# repeat
```

..which is a bit round-a-bout - ideally I could do something like..

```
mv something.py py2.6_something.py # once

2to3 py2.6_something.py --write-file something.py
vim py2.6_something.py
# repeat
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha, you can pipe the 2to3 output to the `patch` command, which can write the modified file to a new file:

```
mv something.py py2.6_something.py
2to3 py2.6_something.py | patch -o something.py
```

Answer (score 1):

2.x should be your codebase of active development, so 2to3 should really be run in a branch or temporary directory. I'm not sure why you'd want to have the 2.x and 3.x versions lying around in the same directory. distutils has a build_2to3 script that will run 2to3 on a 3.0 install.

Comment: So I can quickly/easily edit the 2.x version, run 2to3, run the tests on 3.x (and repeat). If I have a branch for 3.x, how do I quickly make changes to the 2.x branch and regenerate the 2to3'd code?

Comment: Generally, you'd make all your changes on the 2.x branch, and just use 2to3 when you were distributing or trying to port your library.

Comment: I've made the question a bit clearer. I made the py3 branch to contain the changes I had to make to the py2.6 code, so it would 2to3 without errors